# Cocoa - Store an NSString value

Tags: xcode, cocoa, save, storage

I want to store an NSString variable, that I receive from a JSON request, for future use. So when the user loads the app again, it loads that value (an NSString) that I stored.

What is the best way to store that kind of information?

Comment: I would read over this so you're more familiar with the options available to you.  But as the answer below says, NSUserDefaults would probably be best for your situation: https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you're looking for.

Save string:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:theStringToSave forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

Retrieve string:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *theSavedString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anne! You nailed it!